# Can rank ordered mixed logit handle varying set sizes?

Tags: mixed-model, ranking, ranks, ordered-logit

I have data that consist of numerous trials, where each trial is a ranked set of items.  The set of items for each trial is a subset of **varying size** of all possible items.  (I.e. the items are shared between trials, but each trial does not necessarily have all possible items in it)

Does anyone know if ranked ordered mixed logit models can handle sets of rankings in which the size of the set **varies** from set to set?